# Pandas PeriodIndex slicing

Tags: python, pandas

Assume, I have PeriodIndex like that of:

```
base_time_idx = pd.period_range('2020-08-01', periods=8, freq='M')
```

Output:

```
PeriodIndex(['2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', '2020-12', '2021-01',
             '2021-02', '2021-03'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#frequency-conversion-and-resampling-with-periodindex) is documentation of PeriodIndex.

And there are examples of slicing in Series and DataFrame.

But how could I make slice in `base_time_idx` itself, if I want to select subrange from it by that way `base_time_idx['2020-10':]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
base_time_idx[base_time_idx >= '2020-10']
```

I think you can't slice the PeriodIndex without it being in a DataFrame or Series.

Comment: ‍♂️  so simple... )))
And there is no any mention of it in docs.